# Android - transform Classes With Dex For Debug

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

My project was working fine until I added the Facebook dependency.
I've started getting this error.
I've read many question, the problem seems to be related to `MultiDex`.
But none of the solutions worked for me

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 
'/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Even after I remove what I've added, it still show and also gradle  seems to be taking a lot of time while building than usual

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "net.ciblo.spectrodraft"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }

}
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.5'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+'
compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'

}
```

Comment: Do you see a more specific error when you build on the command line with --debug and --stacktrace?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to build with command line

Comment: @HarounSMIDA Can you post the full log from Gradle Console?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Adding the following code to `build.gradle` app module solved my problem

```
android{
    defaultConfig {

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }


    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
dependencies {
    //...
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: So the addition you made is **javaMaxHeapSize "4g"**?

Comment: Yes that's what I've added

Comment: very nice solution, thanks. I tried with just including `multiDexEnabled true` and it went through. I didn't need to include the other lines of code. Test if this works; otherwise, keep adding the rest of what Haroun described.

Answer (score 4):

you can selectively compile Google Play service APIs into your app. For example, to include only the Google Fit and Android Wear APIs, replace the following line in your build.gradle file:

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

with these lines:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0'
```

==> to keep the number of methods in your app (including framework APIs, library methods, and your own code) under the 65,536 limit.

Comment: what APIs should I compile for utilizing maps, geo-fence related framework

Comment: you'll fined what you need here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following in build.gradle fixed the issue for me,

```
android {
//...

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
//...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This horrendous recurring issue hit me again recently. The gradle build stalls permanently at app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug, just running for hours and never completing. This time I fixed it by removing all references to 'fabric', a new layer of Crashlytics being pushed on us.

```
//apply plugin: 'io.fabric'   //REMOVE
//classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'  //REMOVE
```