# :app:transformClassWithDexFor Debug failed error in react native

Tags: android, react-native

Issues during running react native app.

It shows following error:

> :app:transformClassWithDexFor Debug failed error in react native

Please give solution to fix it.
Thanks

Comment: Hi Satyendra, welcome to SO. Please take a moment and look into this to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try this out [same problem maybe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39268997/6832877)

Answer (score 0):

Remove both `build` folder in `/android` and `/android/app`
and build again with `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

From your project directory

```
cd android
```

from cmd as  admin run

```
gradlew clean
```

then you can install app using react-native run-android