# how can I get this flutter app from 2019 running?

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, gradle

I am working on a flutter app from 2019 (untouched until today) and I have this error which I am unsure about.

```
error processing C:\Users\Syed\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8\1.5.30\5fd47535cc85f9e24996f939c2de6583991481b0\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30.jar
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitModule(ClassVisitor.java:148)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readModule(ClassReader.java:731)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:632)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
    at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyze(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:144)
    at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyzeJar(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:92)
    at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyze(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:63)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.lambda$getInitalGraphData$4(DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1448)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
error processing C:\Users\Syed\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try enabling mutiDex? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46494757/11545939

Comment: Check if kotlin is in latest version

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when running the trace project(https://github.com/trentpiercy/trace) on my local. To this specific issue. I updated the gradle version and this exception disappeared.

Under the `android` folder, open `build.gradle` and update the gradle version as follows.(Note, the version was originally 3.2.1. I updated to 4.2.2 although other higher versions could work as well)

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
}
```

And then open the `gradle-wrapper.properties` under gradle/wrapper/ and change the `distributionUrl` to at least version 6.7.1:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip
```

I also encountered some other issues which involves upgrading the android `minSdkVersion` to 28 and `targetSdkVersion` to 31; setting the `org.gradle.java.home` to a local installation JDK home in `gradle.properties`; adding `android:exported="true"` in the `MainActivity` in `AndroidManifest.xml`, etc.