# Integer not passing to ResultActivity.java android

Tags: java, android

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've followed the directions on this said article, but the Integer (c_correct) I'm passing is still not showing.

[How to pass integer from one Activity to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074097/how-to-pass-integer-from-one-activity-to-another)

I've been struggling with this problem for some time now. I've been using the method .setText() and I eventually found out that there are two types. So I made sure to put String.setValue() when putting the integer inside .setText().

P1.java (Player 1)

```
public void checkAnswer(View view){
    final int read_motion = 0;
    onShake(read_motion);
    //get the pressed
    Button answerBtn = (Button) findViewById(view.getId());
    String btnTest = answerBtn.getText().toString();

    String alertTitle;

    if(btnTest.equals(rightAnswer)){
        alertTitle = "Correct: " + rightAnswer;
        //access this value!
        c_correct = c_correct + 1;
    }
    else{
        //add up 2
        alertTitle = "Nope! Turn the screen to change question";
    }

    //prompt
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(alertTitle);
    builder.setMessage("Turn to change the question - Click OK to get Credit");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            if (read_motion > 19) {
                //show redundency b/c we dont now what we're doing
                Intent new_start = new Intent(P1.this,ResultActivity.class);
                new_start.putExtra("P1_Score",c_correct);
                startActivity(new_start);

                showNextQuiz();
            } else {
                showNextQuiz();
            }
        }
        //end of line 131
    });
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.show();
}
```

**What I think the problem is:**
The app implements a Accelerator that would read if the user shakes the phone, so I think whenever the phone shakes, the counter re-sets. But I've looked through the code, and I don't think its the cause of the problem. I've looked through this entire code file, but I don't see any line saying to reset the counter when the phone is flipped.

Here is ResultActivity.java. It takes **c_correct** from both P1.java and P2.java. It would display the numbers in a title screen.

```
  public String text = "J";
    @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

    TextView P1_Score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Score_P1);
    TextView P2_Score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Score_P2);

    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    int intVal = mIntent.getIntExtra("P1_Score",0);
    P1_Score.setText(String.valueOf(intVal));
//    int p1 = getIntent().getIntExtra("P1_Score", 0);
//    int p2 = getIntent().getIntExtra("P2_Score", 0);

 //   P1_Score.setText(String.valueOf(p1));
 //   P2_Score.setText(String.valueOf(p2));
}
```

Yes, I've looked through logcat. That's how I realized there was a Resource$notFoumd Exception that lead to to use String.valOf(). Here is the Logcat:

```
02-24 20:23:58.142 8772-8772/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni 
(already on)
02-24 20:23:58.151 8772-8772/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 
using 
defaults: x86
02-24 20:23:58.626 8772-8793/com.example.mosesapostol.cvtrivia 
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-24 20:23:58.626 8772-8793/com.example.mosesapostol.cvtrivia 
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, 
retrying without...
02-24 20:24:00.622 8772-8772/com.example.mosesapostol.cvtrivia W/zygote: 
Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses 
on 
this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
```

I've also looked at Run also. No signs that there is a NullPointerException or any type of run-time error. 
ring stopped.

Here is the Run Window
 [Picture of Run in android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G15SN.png)

I've even looked up the error: Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!. I already implimented the fix as seen here: 
[Android - transform Classes With Dex For Debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36237253/android-transform-classes-with-dex-for-debug).

I kept changeing the value of c_correct but with no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Even when the varible name is the same, it still doesn't work. Sorry if my code example was misleading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first . Passing parameter in `bundle` will be available on same keys in which they put at the time of sending .

here i see you have put `c_correct` in Key "P1_Score" and getting it with key "Score1" .

Keys should be same . Also check for `int c_correct` value by debugging . 
If you put as "P1_Score" then you should get it with .

```
 Intent mIntent = getIntent();
int intVal = mIntent.getIntExtra("P1_Score",0);
P1_Score.setText(String.valueOf(intVal));
```

Comment: I made the error when posting the problem. Even when the varible is the same, it still doesn't work

Comment: Debug your code. if the statement `if (read_motion > 19)` is true then it should work .